# How to create spring scheduled jobs programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-4

I have a spring scheduler defined as below. I want to create this scheduler programmatically.

What I really want to do is I want to get cronExpression from my database and create executorJob and Trigger dynamically and add them to jobdetails and triggers. I don't need to create quartzProperties dynamically because they won't change. Is there any way to do this?

```
<bean id="testExecutorJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="testExecutor" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="runTest" />
</bean>

<bean id="testTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="testExecutorJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 0/3 1/1 * ? *" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">MyScheduler</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</prop>                
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="testExecutorJob" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="testTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how I run some jobs

```
        sched = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        sched.start();
```

// create a job

```
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(myClass.class)
                    .withIdentity("cronjob", "crongroup")
                    .usingJobData("param1", "someparam")
                    .build();
```

// create trigger

```
        Trigger trigger = trigger = TriggerBuilder
                            .newTrigger()
                            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronString))
                            .build();
```

// scheule it

```
        sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: There are lots of problems I think. My TestExecutor class doesn't extends org.quartz.Job class but some other class. JobBuilder.newJob(myClass.class) needs a class which extends Job class.

Comment: Not `extend` `implements`, your `myClass` needs to implement `Job` - only one method to implement

Comment: I can implement this interface but problem is I got 3 different scheduler method in my TestExecutor class.(like runTest(), runTest2(), runTest3()) I don't know how to override execute method and call this methods on 3 different scheduler tasks.

Comment: On the `Job` you can set a a parameter `.usingJobData("param1", "someparam")` then in the class itself you can test for this